# What is the latest case of employment of Cretan archers in Antiquity?

Tags: military, ancient-history, roman-empire, ancient-greece, roman-republic

It is known that Cretan archers were widely used (presumably as mercenaries) across Mediterranean by Greek armies and were occasionally included in Roman armies of Republic and of Imperial period. I do not remember if there is a secure evidence for that so cannot provide reference, but somewhere I have seen the Cretan archers mentioned in Dacian wars of emperor Trajan.

But what is the latest known case of employment of Cretan archers, supported by reliable evidence? Is there any evidence for the use of Cretan archers in Roman Empire in III-V centuries AD?

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretan_archers) on Cretan Archers states that "_One of the last occasions on which Cretan archers are known to have played a significant role was as part of the garrison defending Constantinople against the Turkish army of Mehmet II in May 1453_".  Are you looking for something more than that?

Comment: This [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Do-the-men-of-Crete-still-practice-their-archery-for-which-they-were-so-famous) mentions the Cretan War 1645–1669 as being "the last verified and undesputed *[sic]* reference to Cretan military archers". Unfortunately, it's not sourced.

Comment: I don't know about Cretans, but there are certainly bow-wielding cretins out there.
https://www.realtree.com/the-realblog-with-stephanie-mallory/man-accidentally-shoots-himself-in-chest-with-crossbow

Comment: Question was edited to be more specific with historical period

Comment: Do you mean Cretan archers fighting *for* Rome or *against Rome*, or either?

Comment: @LarsBosteen, it doesn't matter. Just any evidence that proves that they were still in use, no matter for whom they fought

Comment: According to [Cretan Archers in Roman Service](https://stefanosskarmintzos.wordpress.com/2011/10/24/cretan-archers-in-roman-service/) "In the late roman period Cretans are not mentioned and perhaps they were not distinguished from other auxilia missile troops."

Comment: @LarsBosteen, thanks for the reference! Indeed it seems that Cretan are not mentioned in Notitia Dignitatutm so probably were diluted among other "saggitarii" units, if still were employed